# Where is the virtio_net kernel module in Ubuntu Server 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization

It existed in version kernel version 2.6.31-14-server but it appears to be missing in
2.6.32-22-server and greater. Did it get moved / renamed / forgotten about or deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop with kernel 2.6.32-23-generic, and it has the module under */lib/modules/2.6.32-23-generic/kernel/drivers/virtio*.

If the file really is missing, perhaps you have installed a minimal installation and still need to install some virtualization support, such as *ubuntu-virt-server* package?

Comment: Yes I have it also under the generic kernel but not on the server version of ubuntu.